# Get environment variable of another user?

Tags: c#, windows, environment-variables

I have a windows service program that saves files in the application data folder of the local system user.I also have a windows form that needs to read those files and runs on different user accounts but I don't know how to get the environment variable of another user, specifically the local system. If it is possible i would appreciate an example, thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try `String myEnv = System.getenv("env_name");`?

Comment: Maybe change your program to read and write to the common application data folder instead of the user specific application data folder.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I should probably do that it would make it so much easier, btw what would be a good common application data folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);` and make a subfolder within the folder it returns to store your files. That location is designed to be the non user specific data storage location.

The default location is `C:\ProgramData` but you should use the function to get it instead of hardcoding the path. Also you can't save files in the root of that folder but you can make subfolders and save your files in that.

Comment: Note that *if* the files for one user shouldn't be visible to another user (for example, if they contain information private to that person) you should make sure you set the permissions on the files accordingly.  (If it is OK that other users can read the files, you don't need to bother.)